# Tikz to html, characters in picture, svg error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

This fails to produce working file with `htlatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikz \node (foobar) {$\cong$};
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Changing `\node` to `\node[tex4ht node/escape=true]` does not help. Is there easy way to correct this, or should I forget this and try with `\usetikzlibrary{external}`?

(Putting, for example, `\subset` instead of `\cong` to tikz picture works.)

Comment: I suspect it could be because `\cong` is a macro construction, and subset maps directly to a single character. Congruence can be found from Unicode slot U+02245, so maybe using the `unicode-math`-package could help here?

Comment: After adding `unicode-math` (and changing to `htxelatex`) I got empty page --- even with `\subset` that worked before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the mathematical content is converted to bitmap images by default with `tex4ht`. But as `tex4ht` doesn't know it is inside `svg`, it outputs `<img src=..."` element, which is unsupported in `svg`. If math in the tikz nodes is simple, just characters, you can call htlatex with

```
htlatex filename "xhtml, mathml"
```

this will output all math in mathml, and simple math elements like `\cong` will output as html entities. But if you have fractions or something similar in your nodes, this will fail, because `svg` file doesn't know about `mathml` elements and it will not to render.

Comment: ah, I can think of two ways with `<img>` inside SVG: 1) To put it inside a `<foreignObject>` (with XML namespace defined on it), or 2) change `<img src=...>` to `<image xlink:href=...>` (needs XML namespace defined in the SVG; `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`). Both MathML and SVG (and XHTML) are all XML, so mixing and matching should be possible, I think.