# TeX4ht and PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, tex4ht

I tried to compile the code below with

```
mk4ht htlatex file.tex 'xhtml, charset = utf-8 pmathml' '-cunihtf-utf8-cvalidate'
```

Formulas and text are transcribed, but not graphics. How to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,nccmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=4cm,yunit=2cm,algebraic=true,arrowscale=1.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5) 
\psgrid[gridwidth=0.6pt,subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray,
xunit=0.25,yunit=0.5](-6,-6)(10,5)
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt,Dx=1,Dy=1,labels=none,ticksize=-3pt
0pt]{->} (0,0)(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)
\psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](1.25){\frac{5}{4}}
\psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](0.666666666666){\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{psclip}
{\psframe[linestyle=none](-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)}
{\psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{6*x-3}}%
{\psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{1-(2-3*x)^2}}%
\end{psclip}
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt]
(0,1)(0.666666666666,1)  (0.666666666666,0)
\uput[dl](0,0){O}
\uput[d](1,0){I}
\uput[l](0,1){J}
\uput[ur](1.25,-2){$\mathscr{C}_{f}$}
\uput[ur](0.75,1){$\mathscr{C}_{g}$}
\uput[d](2.42,0){$x$}
\uput[l](0,2.35){$y$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see the answer of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124682/error-using-htlatex-with-tikz-forest-package-invalid-svg-generated.  Capture the content inside `pspicture` environment to another file and generate the PDF and later an image. Call this image in the original file using `includegraphics` command.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that default conversion method used by `tex4ht` to convert pictures to image formats has issues with PSTricks, resp. PostScript specials. The default result:

[image]

The conversion is done by processing the dvi file with some dvi processor such as `dvipng` or `dvisvgm`. Default procedure is to call `dvips` and then `Ghostscript` to convert the postscript file to png. We can modify the process fortunately, using `make4ht` build files. Save the following as `file.mk4` (it should have the same basename as your TeX file):

```
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex{}
else
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
end

 Make:image("svg$",
   "dvisvgm -n -o ${output}  -p ${page} ${source}")
```

compile the document using

```
make4ht -u file.tex "svg,pmathml"
```

(yes, it is an equivalent of your `mk4ht` call). The `svg` option requests to use `svg` as image format for converted pictures,

```
Make:image("svg$",
   "dvisvgm -n -o ${output}  -p ${page} ${source}")
```

configures the image conversion itself.

The result:

[image]